# Should we keep [listings], [lstlisting] or both?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

On the main site, there are two tags about code-formatting inside a LaTeX documents which all refer to `listings` package: [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) and [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstlisting).

- [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) currently has 40 watchers and 2.6k questions, and a very detailed description.
- [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstlisting) currently has 2 watchers and only 83 questions, and it has no description text at all.

Literally [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstlisting) is only a sub-tag of [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings). It is like [tcbposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcbposter) as a sub-tag of [tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcolorbox). Therefore, I think [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstlisting) should be deleted and [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) should be used instead in questions, like what has happened with [tcbposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcbposter).

The only reason, in my opinion, which is "legal" enough to keep the [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstlisting) is that there are some questions about issues in `lstlisting` environment and not related to `\lstinline`. But we can still use [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) for such questions well. This reason seems to be insufficient.

What do you think?

Comment: your argument seems good to me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you please [suggest a tag synonym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/lstlisting/synonyms)? I don't have sufficient reputation in [tag:lstlisting] to do so.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think JouleV's suggestion was to delete lstlisting and re-tag them as listings rather than making a synonym, I think that requires mod action?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think if [tag:lstlisting] becomes a synonym of [tag:listings], every questions tagged [tag:lstlisting] will be tagged [tag:listings] automatically.

Comment: @JouleV yes sure but (separately you could choose to ask a moderator to delete a tag if you think it's confusing) I think I will wait for moderator advice here....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, if [tag:lstlisting] is deleted, questions using this tag will not be retagged.

Comment: @JouleV last time we did such a thing a couple of volunteers spent 10 minutes and just retagged them all and that was a few hundred, not just 80 questions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let's wait for moderators' advice then.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion.  Note there is also a listingsutf8 tag which might also be considered redundant.

Comment: People can vote for the synonym at https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/listings/synonyms